# Joining two tables that has no columns in common

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, join

I am working with two tables with no columns that I can easily join to and get the data I want.

Information about the tables:

I do see something in common in both tables that I might be able to use to join, but I am not sure how it can be done.

**Table1:**  has a column called File_Name.  This column captures the imported file location.
example:  C:\123\3455\344534\3fjkfj.txt.  max Lenth = 200.

**Table2:**  has a column called batch_ID and contains all the records imported by the file listed in table1.
The batch_ID column is exact same thing has the File_Name column in table1.
However, the difference is that it only allows the lenth = 50. 
Pretty much it only shows last 50 characters of a filename and directory  (50 characters from right to left.)
max lenth = 50

Example: ..\344534\3fjkfj.txt (basically cuts off characters if more than 50 in lenth).

How would I join these tables on those two columns?  I know I can create a function and temp tables, but how can I do it without it?

Thanks!

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect title.  It should have been:  Joining two tables that has no columns in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Columns
From   Table1 
       Inner Join Table2
          On Right(Table1.ColumnA, 50) = Right(Table2.ColumnB, 50)
```

Comment: The `RIGHT` on the `Table2` is not necessary

Comment: Would this also work in situation where the file_name/file_ID is (for example:) only 20 character?

Comment: @Lamak I was not trying to give a perfect solution to this problem.  The intent of my post was to show that you can use functions in the join condition.

Comment: @GMastros I wasn't saying that you should give a **perfect** solution (well, in fact, the problem that op is facing doesn't have one, since his data is so that false positives can appear because of the difference on the lengths). Even so, the fact that you can use functions is made when you are using `RIGHT` on table1, I don't see any reason why you would also add that to table2